# How to design job-handling for API

Tags: design, architecture, api-design

I am not sure if this is the correct place to ask, please direct me to the correct place if this is not it.

**Context**

I have written a do-all, keep-all, serve-all API (it started small, then grew out of proportions) to function as User Management System for one of our solutions.

This API keeps track of all data, and also communicates with external APIs to perform some sort of configuration on the user accounts. Some of the endpoints includes:

- User (details: Firstname, Lastname, Email, Mobile, UserCompany)
- UserCompany (retrieved from CMDB)
- Company (Customer retrieved from CMDB)
- Connection (User connected to Company)
- ConnectionSystem (Connection connected to CMDB-System implemented at Customer)
- ConnectionSystemAccess (Access to assets in CMDB-System for Connection)

Example: *UserA* John Doe from *UserCompanyA* Contoso connected to *SystemA* Office365 at *CustomerA* Microsoft with access to *AssetA* ExchangeOnline

The model is something like this:
[image: Model mock-up]

**Question(s)**

So I am looking to expand my system to make it a bit more task-oriented, as well as separating concerns a bit more. Now I am afraid my system has bloated into doing to much (in a way that definitely works for our teams), but still breaking with a lot of principles when it comes to good design. I have also been learning alot since I started (practically no experience with any kind of programming) to where I am today, and I have identified areas of improvement.

1. Task one: Create a job-handling system/API

   - Should this be a separate API, or can I build this into the existing one?
2. Task two: Create workers (I'm thinking here of using the .net core 3 Workers) to handle jobs

I'm thinking RabbitMQ for the job-queuing as we have resources in the company with experience running this software. The different JobTypes would produce different messages that Workers for the different JobTypes will process and report status back to JobAPI.

JobAPI model example (simplified for brevity):
[image: Job API Mock-up]